# How can I establish if an object property has been directly assigned or inherited?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I have a constructor function with a default value:

```
var myObject = function(){
    this.myValue = "default";
}
```

I then instantiate a new object:

```
var newInstance = new myObject();
```

How can I tell if `myValue` is the original default value, and has not been reassigned. I can't check the value, as it could be set to be the same, and that would produce a false positive.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Object.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

```
if (newInstance.hasOwnProperty('myValue')) {
    // original default value
}
```

However, this won't be able to tell you whether or not this happened:

```
newInstance.myValue = 'default';
```

To detect that, you'll need to use something like [getters/setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) and track a private mutation flag:

```
function myObject() {
    var _myValue = "default";
    var _wasMutated = false;

    return {
        get myValue() {
            return _myValue;
        },
        set myValue(x) {
            _myValue = x;
            _wasMutated = true;
        },
        get wasMutated() {
            return _wasMutated;
        }
    }
}

// usage:
var newInstance = new myObject();
newInstance.myValue;                // "default"
newInstance.wasMutated;             // false
newInstance.myValue = "default";
newInstance.wasMutated;             // true
newInstance.wasMutated = false;     // writes have no effect since there's no setter
newInstance.wasMutated;             // true
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is looking for...they want to know if the *value* has changed; `hasOwnProperty` will not tell you this.

Comment: I don't. I want to know if it was set directly. Not whether it has necessarily changed

Answer (score 2):

> *I can't check the value, as it could be set to be the same, and that would produce a false positive.*

If you change your constructor to *not* set that value, and instead set it on the prototype:

```
var myObject = function(){};
myObject.prototype.myValue = "default";
```

...then you can use the [`.hasOwnProperty()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to test whether `myValue` has been overwritten *even if it was set to the same value as the default.*

```
if (!newInstance.hasOwnProperty("myValue")) {
    // has not been assigned another value
}
```

This works because if you later say:

```
newInstance.myValue = "something";
```

...it will create a `myValue` property directly on the instance. And when you use `newInstance .myValue` it automatically retrieves the direct property if it exists or the inherited prototype property otherwise.

```
var newInstance = new myObject();

console.log( newInstance.myValue );                   // "default"
console.log( newInstance.hasOwnProperty("myValue") ); // false

newInstance.myValue = "default";
console.log( newInstance.myValue );                   // "default"
console.log( newInstance.hasOwnProperty("myValue") ); // true
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach (upvote!) but, as always, with defining things on the prototype, one has to keep in mind that that property is then shared among all instances (unless, as you point out, it's overwritten).  Where this can get you in trouble is your property is itself an object.  Consider, then `myObject.myValue.prop = 'foo';`.  Now all instances of `MyObject` that have not overriden `myValue` have changed, and that smells like a side-effect.

Comment: @EthanBrown - You are quite right about properties that are objects. For those of course your approach or Matt's will cover it. I admit I didn't even consider that because I was just thinking of strings as in the OP's example code, but still I think this is a reasonable approach for those primitive value cases as it keeps things very simple. For the OP: use with caution.

Comment: To be more precise; it'll work with any immutable value since you can only change them by assigning a new value to them. So it would work with objects if they're immutable (like String ojbect). Wouldn't work with Array since you can use .splice, .sort .push ... to change it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to accomplish what you're looking for, but it's easy enough to do with a "defaults" object:

```js
var MyObject = function() {
    this.myValue = this.defaults.myValue
}
MyObject.prototype.defaults = { myValue: 'default' };
MyObject.prototype.isDefault = function(prop) { 
    return this[prop]===this.defaults[prop];
}

var o = new MyObject();
o.isDefault('myValue');   // returns true
o.myValue = 'foo';
o.isDefault('myValue');   // returns false
o.myValue = 'default';
o.isDefault('myValue');   // returns true
```

On the other hand, if what you need to know is whether or not a property has ever been set (regardless of it's value), you'll have to use private properties and getter/setter functions:

```js
var MyObject = function() {
    var myValue = 'default';       // i'm private!
    var myValueHasChanged = false;
    this.myValue = function(newVal) {
        if( arguments.length===0 ) {
            return newVal;
        } else {
            myValue = newVal;
            myValueHasChanged = true;
        }
    }
    this.myValueHasChanged = function() {
        return myValueHasChanged;
    }
}

var o = new MyObject();
o.myValue();              // returns 'default'
o.myValueHasChanged();    // returns false
o.myValue('foo');
o.myValue();              // returns 'foo'
o.myValueHasChanged();    // returns true
o.myValue('default');
o.myValueHasChanged();    // returns true
```

Comment: +1. May I suggest `if (arguments.length===0)` rather than `if (newVal===undefined)`, so that it is possible to set the value to `undefined`?

Comment: It's a good suggestion, @nnnnnn.  I generally avoid *ever* using `undefined` as a matter of course (I consider the use of `undefined` reserved for JS itself), but your suggestion does remove that edge case, so I'll change it.